# Display image and text in same line

Tags: css

I want to display image and text in one line like tripadvisor.in/

```
<div style="display:inline-block"> 
<div style="display:inline;float:left">
<a href="CollegeProfile.php" class="white">
<h4 style="margin-bottom:10px;display:inline">Nice college to study</h4></a>
<br /><a href="CollegeProfile.php" class="white">Read reviews of Indian institute of management,Ahmedabad</a>
</div>
</div>


<div style="display:inline-block">
&nbsp;<img class="shakeImage" src="assets/img/author.jpg" style="border: 1px solid white;height:60px;display:inline" />
</div>
```

It shows image and text in separate line like:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to stick using `div` elements, you can do this with the below:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/RvmfR/)

HTML

```
<div class='table'>
    <div class='cell'>
       <a href="CollegeProfile.php"><h4 >Nice college to study</h4></a>
       <a href="CollegeProfile.php">Read reviews of Indian institute of management,Ahmedabad</a>
    </div>
    <div class='cell'>
        <img class="shakeImage" src="assets/img/author.jpg" style="border: 1px solid white;height:60px;display:inline" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table {
    display:table;
}
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
h4 {
    margin:0;
}
```